# what's the c++ STL library using on android framework development

Tags: android, c++, stl, android-ndk

Android provide the c library bionic. It contains libc.so, libdl.so, libm.so, libstdc++.so and the linker.

So when we develop on framework, we can use the method in libc.so and libstdc++.so. But it do not contain the C++ STL.

If we develop on NDK, we have some choose on [C++ Library Support](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html?hl=ml) (libstdc++/GAbi++/STLport/GNU STL/LLVM libc++)

But if we develop on framework like ART. we can use STL class like Stream, Vector. I want to know which STL library we will used?  GUN STL or STLport? I can't find the library set in Android.mk file.

Thanks!

Comment: If you cross compile android c++ using ndk and cmake, by default uses, gnu_stl shared, but you can use any of them, I have been problems with some stl functions using stl_port, for me the best choice is stl_gnu_shared

Comment: From the https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html?hl=ml#hr   The default lib is libstdc++ (default), it means we can't use the STL by default ?     I also want to know , if i build the android source code, which STL library will be used ?

Comment: of course, you can use stl, if you want to use std::vector or std:.string basic stl functions, with gnustl_static or gnustl_shared should be enough.